# add product attribute from external script

Tags: php, eav, magento2.2

> I'm working on a custom import script and I want to check if the
>   product I'm going to import has an attribute that does not exist in
>   Magento, the script will create the attribute

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
if ( $_POST['product'] && validate_key($_POST['key'] )) {

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();    
    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    .
    .
    .
    $eav = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute');
    if ( !$eav->load($code)->getId()  ) {
        $eavFac = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory");

        $eavFac->addAttribute( \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $code,
                        [
                            'group'                     => 'Product Details',/* Group name in which you want to display your custom attribute */
                            'type'                      => 'int',/* Data type in which formate your value save in database*/
                            'backend'                   => '',
                            'frontend'                  => '',
                            'label'                     => $t, /* lablel of your attribute*/
                            'input'                     => 'select',
                            'class'                     => '',
                            'source'                    => 'ModuleNameSpace\YourModuleName\Model\Config\Source\Options',
                            'global'                    => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,  /*Scope of your attribute */
                            'visible'                   => true,
                            'required'                  => false,
                            'user_defined'              => false,
                            'default'                   => '',
                            'searchable'                => true,
                            'filterable'                => true,
                            'comparable'                => false,
                            'visible_on_front'          => true,
                            'used_in_product_listing'   => true,
                            'unique'                    => false
                        ]
                    );
                    $all_attrs[] = $eav->load($code)->getId();

                }
}
```

its giving the error

> Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory::addAttribute()

Comment: what the issue you are facing?

Comment: Call to undefined method Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory::addAttribute()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to replace your code.

```
$eavFac = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory");
$eavFac->addAttribute( \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $code,
```

Replace with this

```
$setup = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface');
$eav_setup_factory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory');

$setup->startSetup();
$eavSetup = $eav_setup_factory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

$eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $code,
```